# Why am I getting "Could not resolve hostname" while trying to connect to my EC2

Tags: macos, networking, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to connect via SSH to my EC2 Instance.

This **works**:

```
ssh ubuntu@ec2-1-111-111-111.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

However, when I try to alias my connection by adding this to my ~/.ssh config:

```
Host my_alias
      Hostname ec2-1-111-222-222.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key.pem
      User ubuntu
```

I receive the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname my_alias: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

When I run the following command:

```
ssh my_alias
```

I am on osx catalina

Comment: What command are you running when you receive that error?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am running `ssh my_alias'. Thank you for pointing that out will update my question.

Comment: I just tried similar and it worked first time (I referenced [Use Your SSH Config File to Create Aliases for Hosts](https://www.howtogeek.com/75007/stupid-geek-tricks-use-your-ssh-config-file-to-create-aliases-for-hosts/)). Are you sure that you are creating the file as `~/.ssh/config`? It looks like it's trying to connect to a computer called `my_alias` rather than using the config file.